# Null constant on querydsl constructor

Tags: querydsl

When i try to use null value on `querydsl` constructor:

```
query_fetch.list(new QFoo(foo.id, .., null));
```

I got a exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 9
```

And when i use `NullExpression` :

```
query_fetch.list(new QFOO(foo.id, .., new NullExpression<>(String.class)));
```

I still got a other exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

stacktrace :

```
janv. 18, 2016 10:54:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/AO] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1932.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ConstructorExpression.newInstance(ConstructorExpression.java:133)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.FactoryExpressionTransformer.transformTuple(FactoryExpressionTransformer.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultList(QueryLoader.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1177.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:333)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:195)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:243)
    at service.administration.RootServ.get_ao_for_root_ref(RootServ.java:179)
    at controller.administration.ValidationAO.get_page(ValidationAO.java:88)
    at controller.administration.ValidationAO.ao_root_ajax(ValidationAO.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1254.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Simon  i want put null values in my constructor

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper I add it.

Comment: Make sure that the expression types match the types of the constructor parameters

Comment: @TimoWestkämper i'm sure it's the same otherwise it will be a compilation error, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to select Foo objects, simply try:

```
query_fetch.list(QFoo.foo);
```

In case you want to select something that doesn't fit your Foo class, you should risk a look at the class ConstructorExpression.

Comment: No i want put null values in my constructor

Comment: Then try: list(ConstructorExpression.create(Foo.class, foo.id, .., new NullExpression<>(Integer.class)))